# How to get key by value in object of keys of arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, get, key

How to get the key from object of keys of array in java script?

```
var object = { "a" : [], "b" : ["S","W"] "c" : ["N","E"]}
```

How can i get the key by the value of "S" in java script?

Answer (score 4):

**Object.keys()**

1. `Object.keys()` will create an array of keys for the object that is in variable `object`
2. `find()` will find the matching key that matches the condition. In your case, matching the `toSearch` text inside the array values of that key, for which you can use `includes()` or even `indexOf(toSearch) !== -1`

```js
var object = { "a" : [], "b" : ["S","W"], "c" : ["N","E"]};
var toSearch = 'S';
var key = Object.keys(object).find((key) => object[key].includes(toSearch));
console.log(key);
```

You can also use another way using `Object.entries()` like:

```js
var object = { "a" : [], "b" : ["S","W"], "c" : ["N","E"]};
var toSearch = 'S';
var key = (Object.entries(object).find(([key, value]) => value.includes(toSearch)) || [])[0];
console.log(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function and pass the object & the val. Inside the function iterate the object using `for..in` and check if the value contains the searched text. If so then push the key in an array & return it. This returned array will contain all the key name which have the searched text in it's value array

```js
var object = {
  "a": [],
  "b": ["S", "W"],
  "c": ["N", "E", "S"]
}

function getKey(obj, val) {
  let keyArr = [];
  for (let keys in obj) {
    if (obj[keys].includes(val)) {
      keyArr.push(keys)
    }
  }
  return keyArr;
}

console.log(getKey(object, 'S'))
```